# Use Thymeleaf to check for specific Stormpath group membership

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, stormpath

I'm trying to determine if the logged in user is a member of a specific Stormpath group.

The following works but it is based on the wrong attribute (groups.href)

```
<div th:text="${#lists.contains(account.groups.href, 'https://api.stormpath.com/v1/accounts/eXaMpLe12345/groups')}" />
```

whereas I am trying to find (pseudo code) `groups.isMemberOf('https://api.stormpath.com/v1/accounts/mYgRrOuP1234/groups')`

I know how to iterate over the groups and print out all their data and I can see the href of the group that I am trying to find, but I don't know how to access it by its href.

```
<div th:if="${account.groups != null}">
    <ul>
       <li th:each="group : ${account.groups}" th:text="${group.href}">group details...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, you would want to let the server side (controller) do the heavy lifting.

So, in the controller, you might have something like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String home(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {

    Account account = AccountResolver.INSTANCE.getAccount(request);

    Group group = client.getResource("https://api.stormpath.com/v1/groups/qjWFpHyC5q6NdakGFCfrb", Group.class);

    if (account != null) {
        model.addAttribute("account", account);
        model.addAttribute("group", group);
        model.addAttribute("isMemberOfGroup", account.isMemberOfGroup(group.getHref()));
    }

    return "hello";
}
```

Then, in your thymeleaf view you could have:

```
    <div th:if="${account}">
        <h4 th:if="${isMemberOfGroup}" th:text="${account.fullName} + ' is a member of the ' + ${group.name} + ' group.'"></h4>
        <h4 th:text="'Account Store: ' + ${account.Directory.Name}"></h4>
        <h4 th:text="'Provider: ' + ${account.ProviderData.ProviderId}"></h4>
    </div>
```

Result:

[image]

Full Disclosure: I am Stormapth's Java Developer Evangelist

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the recommended way is to do the determination of a accounts group access from within the Controller before sending it to Thymeleaf to render. Basically you add a model property related to what you are checking and do that check in the Controller populating that property. Within the template you then validate the property is set as you expected.

https://stormpath.com/blog/build-spring-boot-spring-security-app - Read the section called "Spring Security Access Control By Group Membership"